# Turning LED on/off using java and azure IOT

Tags: java, azure, iot

Can anyone help us. How to communicate with the azure IOT by working on internet of things using java. Help Us one sample example for turning LED on/off using java and azure IOT.

Comment: What have you tried, and what precisely is the problem with it? SO isn't a tutorial service, you'll need to do some research yourself.

Comment: I tried the example as provided in this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-java-java-getstarted{"deviceId":"myFirstJavaDevice","windSpeed":10.156936037930354}

Comment: Then provide a [mcve], and explain where it got you

Comment: In this example https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-java-java-getstarted  we are sending message to azure IOT .({"deviceId":"myFirstJavaDevice","windSpeed":10.156936037930354}). Is azure IOT maintaining any message formats? If i want to switch on the fan , how can i send the message to azure IOT regarding to FAN device?

Comment: I got this example from microsoft.com  and the url for that example (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-java-java-getstarted)

Comment: Where it got you, not where you got it. What happened when you ran that code? [Edit] the question per the [help].

Comment: Asking for examples / tutorials is off-topic. Also - if you're going to add additional details, *edit your question* - don't bury them in comments. Especially when you're adding things like JSON (where formatting is important for readability).

Answer (score 0):

Your description of what you did is not clear, and your question is too broad for SO. Based on my understanding for your description, I can only give some idea for you.

1. To turn LED on/off, you need a micro board as a controller, such as Arduino or Raspberry Pi, to receive the switching signal to control a relay which connect LED with Power Supply, or directly to switch the 3.3V/5V port of the board which connect LED if the LED is enough small.
2. For micro board device with Azure IoT Hub as below.

   - Using Arduino in C/C++ to send device-to-cloud message as heartbeat to Azure IoT Hub for keeping connection & online status, then be ready for receving cloud-to-device message as switching signal from Azure IoT Hub to do the action for switching LED.
   - Using Respberry Pi in Java with Oracle JDK for Linux ARM) or in C# on Windows IoT Core to do the same operations like Arduino above.
3. Using Java to build a application for User Interface to communicate with Azure IoT Hub to send [cloud-to-device](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-java-java-c2d) messages and check these device status.

There are some sample which you can refer to, but not for Java.

1. [Change the on and off behavior of the LED](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-adafruit-feather-m0-wifi-kit-arduino-lesson4-change-led-behavior) on Arduino.
2. Connect your Raspberry Pi 3 device to your IoT hub using [C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-raspberry-pi-kit-c-get-started) and [Node.js](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-raspberry-pi-kit-node-get-started)
3. Connect your Intel Edison device to your IoT hub using [Node.js](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-intel-edison-kit-node-get-started) and [C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-intel-edison-kit-c-get-started)

Hope it helps. Any concern, please feel free to let me know if you can improve your description.

Comment: Thank you so much Peter. Our client is planning to use the zigbee sensors with the  DSR gateway manager .I want to know importantly as two things 1. Get the devices information from azure Iot using java ?2. I think based on the devices the Json parameters should be different for one device to another device while sending messages to azure Iot. I need to know the what and all parameters i need to send to azure IOT based on device?